# Credit card validation problem using multiple textbox

Tags: jquery-validate, credit-card

I'm using multiple textboxes for users to entry different credit cards#, with jquery validations. Ambiguously, only the first text box validation is working. Validation's are not working for the other boxes. There are no js errors too in error console.

It'll be very helpful if someone can please give me a clue.

```
//for first textbox
$("#cust_reg").validate({
  rules: {
    cc_num_local: {
      required: true,
      creditcard: true
    }
  }
  });

//for second textbox 

   $("#cust_reg").validate({
  rules: {
    cc_num_roam: {
      required: true,
      creditcard: true
    }
  }
  });
```

the relevant html only: http://pastie.textmate.org/2422338

Answer (score 0):

You can have more then one HTML element using the id of `cust_reg`. If you do then only one will be available to your JavaScript code since one supersedes the other. It also isn't valid HTML. You'll need to change the name of the second field to be something different like `cust_reg2`.

Comment: `cust_reg` is the name of the form. for the credit-card jquery validation, you've to use the form name. .. 
I solved the problem by sending the first dom element to the validation function on `onblur`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have one form and two different ID's you might try combining them in your code.

```
$("#cust_reg").validate({
  rules: {
    cc_num_local: {
      required: true,
      creditcard: true
    },
    cc_num_roam: {
      required: true,
      creditcard: true    //Not sure if this can be the same name
    }
  }
});
```